# Which set would these red and grey pieces be from?

Tags: set-identification

Hoping for help in identifying which set these bags have come from. These were given to my son but we are missing bag 1 and instructions. Pictures of front and back of packets: [image]

Answer (score 6):

These bags belong to [Neptune Carrier (8075)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8075-1) set.

[image]

Identified by collection of elements, like [Window 1 x 4 x 2 Plane, Single Hole Top and Bottom for Glass](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61345), [Technic, Panel Fairing #18 Large Smooth, Side B](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64682)
, [Wedge 16 x 4 Triple Curved](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=45301) in Red color and [Propeller 7 Blade 6 Diameter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87751) in Pearl Light Gray.

**Instructions** can be [downloaded from LEGO](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/8075). Even though you miss the first bag it contains only minifigs and supplemental models.

[image]

Bags, starting from bag #2, contain elements required to build main model:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. One happy boy here tonight.

Answer (score 2):

These parts are from

[8075: Neptune Carrier](https://brickset.com/sets/8075-1/Neptune-Carrier)
[image]

Keyparts :

- [Red Wedge 16 x 4 Triple Curved](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=45301&colorID=5&in=A)

- [Red Technic, Panel Fairing #18 Large Smooth, Side B](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64682&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

Comment: Thank you very much. One happy boy here tonight.